# Return specific data from a Wikipedia Page using API

Tags: web-scraping, mediawiki-api

I want to parse Geographic pages (i.e. landmarks, places of interest) on Wikipedia to return a json file that only contains only the page title, and the GIS coordinates scraped from the page(s).

So for example, looking at the page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sanctuary

Using the api: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=The%20Sanctuary&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json returns all the data from the page content.

However, I just want to return the following elements:

"title":"The Sanctuary"
coord|51.41000|N|1.83173|W

Please can anyone advise how to correctly structure the web service call?

This is a first attempt at scraping content from pages for me, so any guidance greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule of thumb for scraping is to not do it. Many things are available in the API (use the [API sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox) to discover them). For most other interesting data someone already wrote a library.

In this case, [action=query&titles=The_Sanctuary&prop=coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=The_Sanctuary&prop=coordinates&format=jsonfm) will get you what you want:

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "pages": {
            "788970": {
                "pageid": 788970,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "The Sanctuary",
                "coordinates": [
                    {
                        "lat": 51.41,
                        "lon": -1.83173,
                        "primary": "",
                        "globe": "earth"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tgr. This works perfectly. I'll dive into the API sandbox as you suggest and increase my knowledge - as you've no doubt gathered, this is new territory for me. Thanks again.